# How do you output HTML code using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an external .js file with the following code.

```
function cars() {   
cars=["BMW","Ford","Nissan"];
document.write("<h3>"+Cars+"</h3>");
   for (var j=1;j<cars[j].length;j++)
   {
    document.write("<h2>"+cars[j]+"</h2>");
   }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/cars.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="cars">
      <script>cars();</script>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I view the browser I see the list of cars, but when I view the source code I see 
`"<script>cars();</script>"` where the list should be.  I am having trouble with .innerHTML and how it works with external .js file? Can someone please help me.

Comment: You need to read up on the basics, placing a script tag in an element and using document.write is probably the worst idea ever.

Comment: `document.write` doesn't append to your source code. It works on runtime and clears everything before it writes

Comment: Use the developer tools from your browser (hit F12) to view the dynamic html DOM

Comment: You'll want to use the DOM.

Comment: this is invalid `"<h3>"+Cars+"</h3>"` `Cars` is not a variable. Should see that as error in browser console => `Cars is undefined`

Comment: Incidentally, `for (var j=1;j<cars[j].length;j++)` has a couple of problems - first it should count from 0, not 1, and second you're looking for `j < cars.length`, not `j < cars[j]`.  The middle part of the for loop is the criteria for the loop to keep running, which is whilst `j` isn't bigger than the largest index in the array.  Also in this statement `document.write("<h3>"+Cars+"</h3>");`, `Cars` isn't defined - I suspect you actually want `document.write("<h3>Cars</h3>");`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can create tags like so:

```
$('<h2>').text('hello')
```

jQuery lets you get elements by class or by name, using selectors:

```
$('#cars') //this gets your cars span
```

You can call functions on the returned element, such as to append an element to it:

```
$('#cars').append(some_element)
```

You can create an element for each thing in the array using a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  $('#cars').append($('<h2>').text(cars[i]));
}
```

Or you could use map:

```
$('#cars').append(cars.map(function (car) { return $('<h2>').text(car); }));
```

if you prefer a more functional-esque approach...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the jquery function [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

You have to change some of your code a little, for example, this line:

```
document.write("<h3>"+Cars+"</h3>");
```

Also, remember that `Cars` is not a variable in your script.

you can use:

```
$('#cars_div').append("<h3>Cars</h3>");
```

and create a div with an id called cars_div to write your html code on it.

Another tip, your for loop. Remember that your `cars` array has 3 items. To access the first one you need to do a `cars[0]`. In your for loop, the var `j=1` skips the first one.

If you need the possible solution with jquery, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8DtNv/).

Answer (score 0):

had to modify your javascript a little, but I was able to inspect the HTML just fine [over on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HiEY0vtEkuSYBZS1AL29?p=preview)

[image]